# beginTransaction and commit in postgresql function

Tags: postgresql

i make postgresql function to insert  or update user data without primary key and i can't edite this table or use auto increment

can i use beginTransaction  and commit or any way to lock insert data through this function until anther transaction finished?

becouse if i do two transaction in the same time to insert new user data its take the same id

for example

```
id       | location_id | date_time
------------------------------------------------------
9340934  | 1015        | 2021-09-04 18:17:51.719668+02
-------------------------------------------------------
9340934  | 1043        | 2021-09-04 18:17:51.340677+02
```

Comment: If you really can't change the table, find someone who can. If you can't do that, [create a sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) and use that for your primary keys.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.